# django html editor to add image in CharField form

Tags: django, forms, django-wiki

I m using Django-wiki which use // markItUp! Universal MarkUp Engine, JQuery plugin in article form

But in Django-wiki form used for create or edit articles I don't see how to add an image like in stack overflow [image]

So I would like to create a JS code to add image as in stack overflow.

My question is: how to create that code (is stack overflow code is open source?) and secondly ho can I save image in my Django App?

thanks for any link to help

Comment: I don't understand why you'd want to implement that, I can see on the demo page that `django-wiki` has a way to insert images : https://demo.django-wiki.org/#wiki-toc-images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to add `wiki.plugins.images.apps.ImagesConfig` to your `settings.INSTALLED_APPS` in order to have access to a new panel where you will be able to upload images and insert them in the markdown like so :

```
[image:id align:right size:orig]
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, but I've already add wiki.plugins.images.apps.ImagesConfig  to setting but still not seeing markdown regarding image adding...

Comment: Should I do something else to add this markdown?